# Hand gesture recognition using contour distance - Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

Based on a previous work (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/144559-centroid-contour-for-a-binary-image-containing-multiple-objects) I am trying to plot the contour distance using hand gesture images located in http://cs.mcgill.ca/~pcrane/

Unfortunately, it seems that my plot are not identical, any reason why? Is the calculation wrong?

I only showed the 1st image.

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Script:

```
clc;
clear;

RGB = imread('E:/00000.jpg');
I = rgb2gray(RGB);
binaryImage = imbinarize(I);
binaryImage = bwareaopen(binaryImage,30);
binaryImage = imfill(binaryImage,'holes');
imshow(binaryImage);

%[B,L] = bwboundaries(binaryImage,'noholes'); % no need

boundaries = bwboundaries(binaryImage);
measurements = regionprops(binaryImage, 'Centroid');

centroids = [measurements.Centroid];
% centroidx = centroids(1:2:end); % no need
% centroidy = centroids(2:2:end); % no need

centroidx = centroids(1);
centroidy = centroids(2);

    numberOfBoundaries = size(boundaries, 1);
for k = 1 : numberOfBoundaries %in case that there are more objects
    thisBoundary = boundaries{k};
    boundaryx = thisBoundary(:, 2);
    boundaryy = thisBoundary(:, 1);
    plot(boundaryx, boundaryy, 'r-', 'LineWidth', 2);
    allDistances = sqrt((boundaryx - centroidx(k)).^2 + (boundaryy - centroidy(k)).^2);
end

sequence = rot90(flip(0:numel(allDistances)-1));
plot(sequence,allDistances)
```

Comment: Which plots, and identical to what? You have 3 plots per image there, plotting different things, no? What do you expect to see?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add them

Comment: It seems to me they are pretty close. Note that there is no unique place to start the contour. They started it elsewhere than where you started it. You can use `circshift` to modify one graph to look more like the other.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [link](http://cs.mcgill.ca/~pcrane/) you mentioned in your post my output is:

[image]

It is the same as the figure that is already on this [page](http://cs.mcgill.ca/~pcrane/)! I should say that the figures on that page are the output of a project named "Hand Gesture Recognition" and the second graph shows "Distance vs Ordered Contour Point" which is totally different of yours. Your code does something else!

The second graph on that site is the output of `function [ fingertips ] = getFingertips( x_cont, y_cont, comX, comY, display_info )`. you can download all functions of this project from that site.

I did run your code.There are some questions about it, would you please explain why  you use `[B,L] = bwboundaries(binaryImage,'noholes');` and `boundaries = bwboundaries(binaryImage);` ? they are the same and you don't use `[B,L]` in you code, so you don't need the former, and why  you use `centroidx = centroids(1:2:end);` that is the same as `centroids(1)`?

The code from this [page](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/144559-centroid-contour-for-a-binary-image-containing-multiple-objects) is for assigning a centroid to each object in an image and measure the distance from the centroid to the boundary of object. And you used some lines of that code which didn't give the desired result. You use some extra unnecessary coding assignments and variables that just make it unstructured. please make it better.Thanks

So your result graph is different and it must be , because the goal of your code is totally different.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and input. 
You are right about the unnecessary code lines (fixed).
My aim was to write a code  by myself that create a Distance from centroid to contour/outline/boundary point plot. Following your comments “So your result graph is different and it must be , because the goal of your code is totally different”. I think that this is what my code does (Distance from centroid to contour/outline/boundary point plot), Am I wrong?

Comment: If you have an alternative solution please share. The line: allDistances = sqrt((boundaryx - centroidx(k)).^2 + (boundaryy - centroidy(k)).^2); calculate distance between centroid and a boundary point.